# HTTPS for intranet website

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, lets-encrypt, intranet

My situation is, I have a server running inside a home network which can be connected from the outside through VPN (Zerotier). This network connected to the internet through NAT, thus there is no real public IP.

Now there are some services that requires HTTPS. Also using self-signed certificate would be quite troublesome as some other service is running inside container (and adding root CA for everyone of them can be a real pain). For example, I have `drone` running inside a container, and it needs to communicate to the `gitea` server through https protocol (or at least the document mentioned that).

So I need a valid certificate to run those services.

I do own a few domain name, and a couple of website operated by a hosting provider.

Now I'd like to know what are my options to get a certificate to run my intranet websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make public DNS records for your domain with your LAN addresses. So, `drone.mybigcompany.com` pointing to 192.168.1.1. You can then obtain the certificate in all kinds of ways. Let's Encrypt will be difficult, but you can also buy certificates and use CNAME verification. You can buy one for less than $10 per year. No need for a fancy one.

Comment: I decided to use Cloudflare as the DNS for one of my domain. Then I'm able to make Caddy (which I use as a web server) to get the certificate from Let's Encrypt for me. It seems to work right now.